# Как использовать несколько конфиг файлов в Spring Boot проекте?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

По умолчанию в **Spring Boot** проекте используется конфиг файл `src\main\resources\application.properties` как к этому проекту можно подключить еще один конфиг файл, допустим `src\main\resources\config\site.yml`

или же, если нельзя, как вы храните секретные данные, что бы они были использованные в проекте, но не были в git-де

Comment: Обычные "секретные" данные хранятся как env variables или в secret storage engine. Например, в hashicorp vault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config\site.yml")
public class MyConfig {}
```

Comment: спс. то что нужно.